# How to get the proper values after a html table parse with ruby/nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby, html-table, nokogiri

I have searched and searched for 3 days straight now trying to get a data scraper to work and it seems like I have successfully parsed the HTML table that looks like this:

```
<tr class='ds'>
<td class='ds'>Length:</td>
<td class='ds'>1/8"</td>
</tr>
<tr class='ds'>
<td class='ds'>Width:</td>
<td class='ds'>3/4"</td>
</tr>
<tr class='ds'>
<td class='ds'>Color:</td>
<td class='ds'>Red</td>
</tr>
```

However, I can not seem to get it to print to csv correctly.

The Ruby code is as follows:

```
Specifications = {
:length => ['Length:','length','Length'],       
:width => ['width:','width','Width','Width:'],  
:Color => ['Color:','color'], 
.......
}.freeze

def specifications
  @specifications ||= xml.css('tr.ds').map{|row| row.css('td.ds').map{|cell| cell.children.to_s } }.map{|record| 
  specification = Specifications.detect{|key, value| value.include? record.first } 
  [specification.to_s.titleize, record.last]  }
end
```

And the csv is printing into one column (what seems to be the full arrays):

```
[["", nil], ["[:finishtype, [\"finish\", \"finish type:\", \"finish type\", \"finish type\", \"finish type:\"]]", "Metal"], ["", "1/4\""], ["[:length, [\"length:\", \"length\", \"length\"]]", "18\""], ["[:width, [\"width:\", \"width\", \"width\", \"width:\"]]", "1/2\""], ["[:styletype, [\"style:\", \"style\", \"style:\", \"style\"]]"........
```

I believe the issue is that I have not specified which values to return but I wasn't successful anytime I tried to specify the output. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
[specification.to_s.titleize, record.last]
```

to

```
[specification.last.first.titleize, record.last]
```

The `detect` yields e.g. `[:length, ["Length:", "length", "Length"]]` which will become
`"[:length, [\"Length:\", \"length\", \"Length\"]]"` by `to_s`. With `last.first` you can extract just the part `"Length:"` of it.

In case you encounter attributes not matching to your `Specification`, you could just drop the values by changing to:

```
    xml.css('tr.ds').map{|row| row.css('td.ds').map{|cell| cell.children.to_s } }.map{|record|  
      specification = Specifications.detect{|key, value| value.include? record.first }
      [specification.last.first.titleize, record.last] if specification 
    }.compact
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that tweak and it spit me back:       rake aborted!
undefined method `last' for nil:NilClass

Comment: This happens if you have data in your HTML which does not fit to `Specifications` (when no key is found by `detect`, you got `nil`). You previous code would happily convert the `nil` into a string and you obtained `"["", nil]"` for it. The question is what do you want to see in that case.

Comment: I am not sure if this helps but I have this at the end of of the ruby text (for the csv): # CSV header fields
  # Format = :field_name => defaultvalue
  F = {:item_name => nil,:length => nil, :width => nil, :Type => nil, ... }.freeze

Comment: I would just want it to spit back an empty value into the csv

Comment: Yes, but for which field/column. What if you receive a line "Taste: Bad"? It's neither length nor width nor color.

Comment: I would want to ignore it. There are many table tds with data that I dont need so I just want to pull the values the match the field names in Specifications = {
:length => ['Length:','length','Length'],       
:width => ['width:','width','Width','Width:'],  
:Color => ['Color:','color'], 
.......
}.freeze  - everything else can just be tossed/ignored/deleted